# How do I install konversation 1.6.2 with QCA support in 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I've downloaded konversation via `apt-get install konversation`, which installs konversation 1.6. This is not the newest version of konversation (v 1.6.2), which normally would not be an issue for me; however, konversation v1.6 was built without QCA support meaning blowfish encryption doesn't function as it should.

Please see this link for more information: [Debian Bug report logs - #798036
konversation: 1.6 Built without QCA support](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798036)

I was wondering, is there anyway to get the new version of konversation via apt-get, or do I have to wait until it is added to the repositories? I've tried building konversation 1.6.2 from source, but I get an endless amount of errors from CMAKE regarding dependencies among other things. I've tried `apt-get build-dep konversation`, but I have a feeling that it isn't getting the correct dependencies. What's interesting is that when I run `apt-get install konversation`, I get version 1.6 installed on my system (as said before). But, when I run `apt-get source konversation` I get the source files for version 1.5 of konversation.

Ultimately, I'd like to get the new version via `apt-get install` as that is the easiest way for me, but if someone can walk me through building from source then that would be great too.

Comment: are you using 16.04?

Comment: Yes I am using 16.04

Comment: How do you use QCA in konversation. Because it looks like the report was against konversation version 1.6-1. But Ubuntu's version is 1.6-0

Comment: I believe the bug report also applies to version 1.6.0 as well. QCA is a library that konversation should normally be built with so that it can use FiSH encryption/decryption. One way to test that it is working is to open a query with another IRC user who is known to have a FiSH plugin installed on their IRC client. Once that query is open you issue the /keyx command to exchange keys with the other IRC user.

Comment: If issuing the /keyx command to another IRC user in version 1.6.0 I get the following error message: [07:08] [Error] Setting an encryption key requires Konversation to have been built with support for the Qt Cryptographic Architecture (QCA) library. Contact your distributor about a Konversation package with QCA support, or rebuild Konversation with QCA present.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using Kubuntu/KDE/Plasma? Konversation depends on a lot of things in the KDE framework

Comment: I am using ChaletOS (Ubuntu 16.04). Currently I am using whichever dependencies came with version 1.6 of Konversation.

Comment: @Billy ChaletOS is not Ubuntu and You should have inform it long ago.

Comment: My apologies @Anwar. In any case, the compile/install instructions you have provided have worked and QCA/FiSH is working as it should! Kudos to you. May I ask how you knew which dependencies were needed for install?

Comment: Also, is it safe to remove the old version of konversation via "sudo apt-get remove konversation"?

Comment: @Billy Actually it was not as hard as I thought. cmake made objection about kf5-x-y thing and I used `apt-cache search kf5 | grep dev` and the library wanted are pretty obvious from there. And some googling. Yes, you can remove older one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update with compile instruction

I'm following [this guide](https://userbase.kde.org/Konversation/Sources#Build_dependencies) to installed

1. First install the packages needed to build

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake extra-cmake-modules qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev libkf5archive-dev  libkf5bookmarks-dev libkf5config-dev libkf5configwidgets-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5coreaddons-bin-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5emoticons-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5idletime-dev  libkf5notifyconfig-dev libkf5notifications-dev libkf5wallet-dev libkf5parts-dev kdoctools-dev libphonon4qt5-dev libphonon4qt5experimental-dev libqca-qt5-2-dev
   ```
2. Clone the latest sources

   ```
   git clone git://anongit.kde.org/konversation
   ```
3. After clone use the instruction from there

   ```
   cd konversation
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<desired install location> ../
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Now you can start using it. Check the using `konversation --version`.

I've tested it on a server with Ubuntu 16.04. If anything goes wrong, let me know it in the comment.

---

#### Old answer

The [bug #798036](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798036) you've referred is for **konversation** version `1.6-1` and fixed in `1.6-2` in Debian.

But Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerux) is still behind version `1.6-1`. It provides `1.6-0` and no evidence is found that this bug is present on `1.6-0` too!

Here is the changelog of the package konversation in Ubuntu - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/k/konversation/konversation_1.6.1-1ubuntu2/changelog

Also the bug was found and fixed around September, 2015 (See [revision 7615](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~neon/konversation/trunk/changes/7618?start_revid=7638)), where the package konversation for Ubuntu Xenial was uploaded around April, 2015 (Check [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/konversation/+changelog))

---

About your other issue that you're getting konversation version 1.5 with `apt-get source`, I haven't experienced that. I used same `apt-get source` and it gave me the exact version of source package, whose binary is available via `apt-get install`

Therefore I recommend not to recompile it yourself because that may break existing QT and KDE systems and could be hard to get updates from Ubuntu.

Comment: In your changelog it shows the bug fix for QCA:

Comment: konversation (1.6-2) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Add have-qca2-needs-to-be-defined.patch
    Andy Irving noticed an ordering problem that prevented
    Konversation from detecting it had QCA available.
    (Closes: #798036)

Comment: @Billy yes. I said in the answer, it is fixed in 1.6-2.

Comment: Ok, I opened the changelog and admittedly didn't read the rest of your answer. Given that you recommend I stop trying to compile on my own, should I just wait until the new package is uploaded?

Comment: I recommend so. I'm not sure if 1.6-2 will be available for Xenial. Most probably they may backport it. However, It'll be in Yakkety (16.10) by default.

Comment: You can grab the upstream source for konversation and try compiling it yourself.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the term "upstream source". Does that differ from the developers source? If so, is there a different method to compiling it?

Comment: No. The original developer's sources are called "upstream source" afaik. methods are mostly same but debian/ubuntu packages have extra steps for packaging

Comment: I see. I've already tried compiling from source and CMAKE throws a bunch of errors, most of which I do not understand.

Comment: @Billy I'm interested in building this. If I could built, I'll update the answer

Comment: Excellent! Shall I remove the currently installed version of konversation via apt-get remove? Also, will that get rid of the dependencies for that version, so that I can grab the new ones for the new version when you post the install instructions?

Comment: Wait until update

Comment: @Billy I've updated the answer. Check and try the solution and report me